# Score display issue in Android app

Tags: bug, android-app, achievements-dialog

I got two upvotes on an answer and 20 points from it. The achievements view used to show +20, but now it shows +10. The answer is less than a day old.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This site does not have MathJax/LaTex enabled. Please don't use formatting like `$20$`, but rather `*20*` or `**20**`.

Comment: @Shadow Forgot. I'll just leave off the dollar signs.

Comment: Well, it's fine to emphasise. :)